# How to accept a full and partial input String from the user?

Tags: c

I am working on a C program which accepts a string from the user.

add, show, printall, find, delete, and quit.

The program must allow the user to type a partial or full option name (listed above) to choose an option.

*For example, if the user gives 'a' or 'ad', the program must accept it as an option for add.* (I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH THIS PART)

My code below:

```
while(strcmp(input, "quit") != 0)
{

printf("Add a record");

printf("\nShow a record");

printf("\nDelete a record");

printf("\nFind a record");

printf("\nPrint all records");

printf("\nQuit");

scanf("%s", &choice);

  
/*Above it says it should accept a or ad for 'add'. In my actual code it only accepts add. That's what I need help with. */  
if(strcmp(choice, "add") == 0)
{
     addMenu(&start);
}
else if(strcmp(choice, "delete") == 0)
{
   deleteMenu(&start);
}
else{
    printf("\nInvalid menu choice!");
}... other options
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` does an exact match. You probably need to add special checks for "a" or "ad".

Comment: If your are allowing any prefix, checking the first character will be sufficient enough.

Comment: @TonyTannous only if it's acceptable to treat e.g. `funk` as `find` as well.

Comment: @Siguza in that case it wouldn't work. That's right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably to combine `strlen` and `strncmp`:

```
size_t len = strlen(choice);
if(strncmp(choice, "add", len) == 0)
{
    addMenu(&start);
}
// likewise for the rest
```

If there is only `"a"`, it will only compare the first char.
With `"add"` it will compare three characters.
With `"adda"` it will try to compare four, which will hit the null terminator of the `"add"` literal, and fail.

You might want to make sure that `len != 0` though, otherwise it would match every command.

Comment: I tried to upvote you but it says "votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". I am going to try it! Thanks a lot